# commandlink action doesn't fire inside p:accordion

Tags: jsf, commandlink

I have command link inside an accordion inside of primefaces wizard and they're all in the same form - I don't have nested forms and yet the action of the command link is not fired.
Here's my page:

```
    <ui:define name="content">
       <h:form id="createSubject"> 
        <p:wizard flowListener="#{createWizard.flowListener}" widgetVar="wiz" showNavBar="false">  
        <p:tab id="personal" title="#{createWizard.tab1Title}">  
          ....
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab id="conclusion" title="#{createWizard.tab2Title}">  
          <p:panel header="#{createWizard.panel2Title}">  
            <p:accordionPanel value="#{createWizard.similarSubjects}" var="subject">  
                <p:tab title="#{subject.VPrenom} #{subject.VNom}"> 
                   <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="5">  
                     <h:outputText value="#{createWizard.firstName}: " />  
                     <h:outputText value="#{subject.VPrenom}" />  
                     <h:commandLink  value="#{createWizard.completeSheet}" actionListener="#{createWizard.completeSubjectSheet(subject.VIdPool)}"/>
                    </h:panelGrid>  
                 </p:tab>  
            </p:accordionPanel>  
         </p:panel>  
         </p:tab> 
         </p:wizard>
         <p:commandButton value="#{createWizard.nextButtonTitle}" onclick="wiz.next()" style="float:right;"/>
         </h:form>
        </ui:define>
```

and my backing bean method:

```
    public void completeSubjectSheet(String subId){
    mk.sdc.helpers.Link link = mk.sdc.helpers.Link.getLink();
    try {
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(link.mkLink("/POOL/view.jsp?V_ID_POOL="+subId));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CreateWizard.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: any chance that wiz.next() returns false ?

Comment: the problem is the h:commandlink inside the accordion not the commandbutton. wizard works great.

Answer (score 1):

Because actionListener can't take any arguments, you have to use action attribute for commandLink.

**EDIT**

Can you use `h:link` or `h:outputLink` for that?Like

`<h:link outcome="/POOL/view.jsp?V_ID_POOL=#{subject.id}" />`

Comment: Do you have there <p:messages /> tag for debugging?So you can see all errors (if there are some)

Comment: I need to redirect from the backing bean to jsp page with parameters what can I use to make that work? Please see my backing bean method...

Comment: @Questionmark: is the action method now invoked or not? A different question should be asked in a different question.

Comment: It's not invoked... Why can't I use commandLink or commandButton? I read your post on why commandLink/button is not being fired... I checked and I don't have nested forms. I posted my jsf code and my backing bean method... What am I doing wrong?